# Ошибка в vivus.min.js

Tags: javascript, wordpress

После подключения, анимация работала и ошибки не было, но после переноса на wordpress, появилась ошибка

```
vivus.min.js?ver=1:124 Uncaught Error: Vivus [constructor]: "element" parameter is not valid (or miss the "file" attribute)
at i.setElement (vivus.min.js?ver=1:124)
at new i (vivus.min.js?ver=1:13)
at arrowAnim.js?ver=1.0.0:1
```

Подключение скриптов правильное, все остальные скрипты работают, но ошибка остается.

Первый пункт ошибки в этом коде:

```
switch (e.constructor) {
        case window.SVGSVGElement:
        case window.SVGElement:
        case window.SVGGElement:
            this.el = e, this.isReady = !0;
            break;
        case window.HTMLObjectElement:
            r = this, (t = function(t) {
                if (!r.isReady) {
                    if (r.el = e.contentDocument && e.contentDocument.querySelector("svg"), !r.el && t) throw new Error("Vivus [constructor]: object loaded does not contain any SVG");
                    r.el && (e.getAttribute("built-by-vivus") && (r.parentEl.insertBefore(r.el, e), r.parentEl.removeChild(e), r.el.setAttribute("width", "100%"), r.el.setAttribute("height", "100%")), r.isReady = !0, r.init(), r = null)
                }
            })() || e.addEventListener("load", t);
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error('Vivus [constructor]: "element" parameter is not valid (or miss the "file" attribute)')
    }
```

Второй пункт ошибки вот тут

```
 function i(t, e, n) {
    r(), this.isReady = !1, this.setElement(t, e), this.setOptions(e), this.setCallback(n), this.isReady && this.init()
}
```

А код с подключением анимации вот этот:

```
const arrowAnim = new Vivus(
  'arrow',
  {
    type: 'oneByOne',
    duration: 70
  }
);
const arrowAnim2 = new Vivus(
  'arrow2',
  {
    type: 'oneByOne',
    duration: 70
  }
);
```

Как можно убрать эту ошибку и чтобы анимация заработала?

Код HTML до загрузки на WP

```
<object id="arrow" type="image/svg+xml" data="./img/svg/arrow__form.svg" class="arrow__form1"></object>
<object id="arrow2" type="image/svg+xml" data="./img/svg/arrow__form2.svg" class="arrow__form2"></object>
```

Код HTML после загрузки на WP

```
 <object id="arrow" type="image/svg+xml" data="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/svg/arrow__form.svg" class="arrow__form1  cursor-btn"></object>
 <object id="arrow2" type="image/svg+xml" data="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/svg/arrow__form2.svg" class="arrow__form2 cursor-btn"></object>
```

После изменил на прямой путь и ничего не помогло

```
 <object id="arrow" type="image/svg+xml" data="/wp-content/themes/WebFocus%20-%20Krasnodar/assets/img/svg/arrow__form.svg" class="arrow__form1  cursor-btn"></object>
 <object id="arrow2" type="image/svg+xml" data="/wp-content/themes/WebFocus%20-%20Krasnodar/assets/img/svg/arrow__form2.svg" class="arrow__form2 cursor-btn"></object>
```

Comment: очевидно, что неправильно указан путь к файлу, об этом вам и сообщает текст ошибки, что файла нет там

Comment: Я изменил на прямой путь и ничего не помогло:( картинка появляется на сайте, но анимации этой картинки нет:(

Comment: где у вас подключен скрипт? он должен быть подключен после отрисовки DOM

Comment: Скрипт подключен в конце документа (библиотека и код который вызывает анимацию), и если я на код, который вызывает анимацию, повешу DOMContentLoaded, то появляется та же ошибка, а если уберу, то появляется ошибка Vivus is not defined

Comment: поменяйте на абсолютный путь, чтоб исключить возможность ошибки с путем. Вместо '/wp-content/themes/WebFocus%20-%20Krasnodar/assets/img/svg/arrow__form2.svg' напишите 'https//:www.yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/WebFocus%20-%20Krasnodar/assets/img/svg/arrow__form2.svg'

Comment: Сделал так, и все равно ошибка (но картинка появляется на сайте). Даже если я удалю вообще эту картинку, то тогда картинка не появляется, но ошибка та же